# eh Controversy.. is this a good practice?

Tags: java, exception

Is the use of `NullPointerException` recommended in this case:

```
/**
 * Drop the database referenced by the singleton.
 * 
 * @throws NullPointerException
 */
public static void dropDatabase() throws NullPointerException {
    if (store != null) {
        store.dropDatabase(DATABASE);
    } else {
        throw new NullPointerException("No valid database connection.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well it's pretty pointless code in that you'd still get a `NullPointerException` if it unconditionally called `store.dropDatabase`. You wouldn't get the same message, but the stack trace would make it pretty clear.

In this case I would say it should be an `IllegalStateException` though:

> Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation.

Sounds exactly like the situation to me. I'd also do the check *first*, like this:

```
if (store == null)
{
    throw new IllegalStateException("No valid database connection.");
}
store.dropDatabase(DATABASE);
```

That way you can get all the preconditions out of the way at the start of the method, and then focus on the main body.

With [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), I'd just change this to:

```
Preconditions.checkState(store != null, "No valid database connection.");
store.dropDatabase(DATABASE);
```

Comment: `IllegalStateException` fits well.

Comment: @wulfgar.pro: Guava is a lovely library, and should be in every Java programmer's toolkit :)

Answer (score 0):

It's OK. Ideally, you should not be needing to write `if ... else`, the `dropDatabase` method, if using `store` in any useful way, will throw NPE automatically.